# Get directories included in Windows Media Center libraries

Tags: c#, windows-7, mediacenter

I'm writing an add-in for Media Center (the version that comes with Windows 7) and want to retrieve the list of physical directories which the user has included in the media libraries (pictures, videos, recorded tv, movies, music).

The Media Center object model (`Microsoft.MediaCenter.*`) does not seem to have any provision to get this information.

The registry has a key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Media Center\MediaFolders`, however these are always empty.

There appears to be a complete list of the directories in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\wmpfolders.wmdb`, but there's no way to tell which media library each directory relates to and, since these are the settings for Media Player, their presence may just be coincidental.

Does anyone know how to *reliably* retrieve a list of these directories, preferably from within the add-in assembly (i.e. using C#)?

Comment: hmm, one question would those media libraries possibly be the playlists ? I never used to the libraries or the playlists but I imagine they might be same thing. Also there is a [Library Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562425(v=VS.85).aspx) maybe check that out.

Comment: @Reza Playlists seem to be regarded as a separate concept both by Media Player and Media Center. It's unclear whether Shell Libraries correspond to Media Center Libraries, since they were only introduced in Windows 7 and i'm sure Vista Media Center still had the concept I refer to in my question.

Comment: I would attach detour to MediaCenter processes and see which registry values or config files are being accessed by it. That might provide some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Reflector to take a peak at how ehshell does this. For Pictures, Videos, Music, and Recorded TV it's using an imported method from ehuihlp.dll. For Movies it just pulls the list directly from `HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Media Center\MediaFolders\Movie`.

Here's an example of how to use the imported method:

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices`;

...

```
[DllImport(@"c:\Windows\ehome\ehuihlp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int EhGetLocationsForLibrary(ref Guid knownFolderGuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] out string[] locations);
```

...

```
Guid RecordedTVLibrary = new Guid("1a6fdba2-f42d-4358-a798-b74d745926c5");
Guid MusicLibrary = new Guid("2112ab0a-c86a-4ffe-a368-0de96e47012e");
Guid PicturesLibrary = new Guid("a990ae9f-a03b-4e80-94bc-9912d7504104");
Guid VideosLibrary = new Guid("491e922f-5643-4af4-a7eb-4e7a138d8174")
```

...

```
string[] locations;
EhGetLocationsForLibrary(ref PicturesLibrary, out locations);
```

Comment: Wow, i'm impressed! I'll put it to the test and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: It works, thanks! FYI, I changed the `DllImport` location to a relative path (in case Windows isn't installed on drive C) and added a second import for the 32-bit version in eHome\WoW) which kicks in if the first throws `BadImageFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ListItems(ListMakerItem listMakerItem)
{
    if (listMakerItem.MediaTypes == Microsoft.MediaCenter.ListMaker.MediaTypes.Folder)
    {
        // Recurse into Folders
        ListMakerList lml = listMakerItem.Children;
        foreach (ListMakerItem listMakerChildItem in lml)
        {
            ListItems(listMakerChildItem);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        BuildDirectoryList(listMakerItem.FileName)
     }
}

private void BuildDirectoryList(string fileName)
{
   // Parse fileName and build unique directory list
}
```

This is an indirect way, but would enable you to build the desired list of directories. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee525804.aspx for more info.

Comment: Can this be done non-interactively, or does obtaining a `ListMakerItem` have to involve the user?